# Coins and balls

Tags: probability

> a fair coin was tossed $3$ times, after each toss, if the coin was on Head a black ball was entered to the urn, if Tail, a white ball.
>
> a.At the end of the experiment $3$ balls are withdrawn from the urn one after the other
>   
>   1. what is the probability that $3$ white balls were withdrawn?
>   
>   2. if $3$ white balls were withdrawn, what is the probability that in the urn were exactly 3 white balls
>
> b. the experiment is done over again, just that in this case a ball is withdrawn and then return to the urn, the process is repeated $3$ times

a.1 $3$ tosses of the coin co-respond to choose a ball so to withdraw 3 white ball $|\Omega|$ needs to be $\{white,white,white\}$ and the probability for that is $(\frac{1}{2})^3=\frac{1}{8}$.

a.2 A=were 3 white balls,B=3 white ball were withdrawn.

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}= \frac{\frac{1}{8}\cap1}{3\choose 3}=\frac{1}{8}$

b.1 There are 3 options: 1/2/3 white ball in the urn so it is
 $$(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3}) +(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3})$$

b.2 how should i approch this?

Comment: Before you conducted the experiment, were there balls already there in the Urn?

Comment: @satishramanathan It empty

Answer (score 2):

During part $a$ we are drawing balls *without replacement*.  It is during part *b* that we are drawing balls *with replacement*.  I.e. during part $a$, the three balls we draw are exactly the three balls that were in the urn (with no repeats and none left behind).

a1) WITP that three white balls were drawn?

This could only have happened if the coinflip sequence was $(tails, tails, tails)$, which occurs with probability $(\frac{1}{2})^3 = \frac{1}{8}$

a2) Given that we draw three white balls from the urn, what is the probability that there were 3 white balls in the urn?

During part $a$, again, we are drawing without replacement, so the only way to draw three white balls is if there were three white balls to be drawn.  If there were three white balls to be drawn, you will of course draw three white balls.  The probability is therefore $1$.  From a definition standpoint, letting $A$ be the event that there are three white balls in the urn and $B$ be the event that there were three white balls drawn, you have $Pr(A|B) = \frac{Pr(A)Pr(B|A)}{Pr(B)} = \frac{\frac{1}{8}\cdot 1}{\frac{1}{8}} = 1$, noting that $Pr(A)=Pr(B)=\frac{1}{8}$

b1) Note first that there are four cases to consider: there are no white balls in the urn, there is one white ball in the urn, there are two white balls in the urn, there are three white balls in the urn.  Represent these cases with $A_0, A_1, A_2, A_3$ respectively.  Note that $A_i\cap A_j =\emptyset$ whenever $i\neq j$ and that $\bigcup A_i = \Omega$ (i.e. these form a partition of the samplespace).

Now, by properties of partitions (and more generally disjoint events) the probability that three white balls were drawn is:

$Pr(B) = Pr(B\cap \Omega) = Pr(B\cap (\bigcup A_i)) = Pr(\bigcup(B\cap A_i)) = Pr(B\cap A_0) + Pr(B\cap A_1) + Pr(B\cap A_2) + Pr(B\cap A_3)$

Continue by applying the multiplication principle to each.  E.g. $Pr(B\cap A_2) = Pr(A_2)\cdot Pr(B|A_2) = \frac{3}{8}\cdot (\frac{2}{3})^3$

> You get then that $Pr(B) = \frac{1}{8}\cdot (\frac{0}{3})^3 + \frac{3}{8}(\frac{1}{3})^3 + \frac{3}{8}\cdot (\frac{2}{3})^3 + \frac{1}{8}\cdot(\frac{3}{3})^3 = \frac{0+3+24+27}{8\cdot 27}=\frac{54}{8\cdot 27} = \frac{1}{4}$

b2) Given that you draw three white balls, what is the probability that all of the balls in the urn were in fact white?

Letting $A$ again represent all balls in the urn are white, and $B$ represent that we draw three white balls, using Baye's Theorem again like before, $Pr(A|B) = \frac{Pr(A)Pr(B|A)}{Pr(B)}$.  Use the value for $Pr(B)$ that we just calculated in the previous part and the top of the fraction is easily calculated.

> $=\frac{\frac{1}{8}\cdot 1}{\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: It has come to my attention I had an arithmetic error during the calculations on the spoiler tags.  The mistake has now been corrected.  The method remains unchanged and still works for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> a.At the end of the experiment 3  balls are withdrawn from the urn one after the other

Let $X$ be the count of white balls placed in the urn. $$X\sim\mathcal{B}(3,1/2) \\ \mathsf P(X=k)=\binom{3}{k} (\tfrac 1 2)^3$$

Let $Y$ be the count of white balls with drawn.

> 1. what is the probability that 3  white balls were withdrawn?

Clearly it's the probability that 3 white balls were placed in the urn.

$$\mathsf P(Y=3) = \mathsf P(X=3) = \frac 1 8$$

> 2. if 3  white balls were withdrawn, what is the probability that in the urn were exactly 3 white balls

Clearly if no balls (or paint) are in the urn, we add three balls, then remove them, and find that they are white, then the probability that they were white when they went into the urn is :...

$$\mathsf P(X=3\mid Y=3) = 1$$

---

> b. the experiment is done over again, just that in this case a ball is withdrawn and then return to the urn, the process is repeated 3  times

The event that any ball drawn is white is independent of the event of any other *when conditioned* on the count of white balls in the urn.  $\mathsf P(Y=h\mid X=k) = \binom{3}{k} (\tfrac{k}{3})^h(\tfrac{3-k}{3})^{3-h}$

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(Y=3)
& = \mathsf E(\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X))
\\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(X=3)\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X=3)+\mathsf P(X=2)\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X=2)+\mathsf P(X=1)\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X=1)+\mathsf P(X=0)\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X=0)
\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 1 8 \cdot 1 + \tfrac 3 8 \cdot (\tfrac 2 3)^3 + \tfrac 3 8 \cdot (\tfrac 1 3)^3+ \tfrac 1 8\cdot (\tfrac 0 3)^3
\\[3ex]
\mathsf P(X=3\mid Y=3) & = \frac{\mathsf P(X=3)\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X=3)}{\mathsf P(X=3)\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X=3)+\mathsf P(X=2)\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X=2)+\mathsf P(X=1)\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X=1)+\mathsf P(X=0)\mathsf P(Y=3\mid X=0)}
\\ & = \frac{27}{1\cdot 27 + 3 \cdot 8 + 3 \cdot 1+ 1\cdot 0}
\end{align}$$